# jquery validation engine REGEX for price to accept both non floating point and 1 or 2 floating point

Tags: regex, jquery-validation-engine

I am trying to get the right regex for price that can accept

(valid)
numbers like 1,2,100,200,2020,10000000
decimal number (1 or 2 floating point) like 1.1, 2.20, 500.45, 10000.2,

(invalid)
characters like abc, etc
more than 2 floating point - 2.22222, 444.444444, 222.333

currently, i have this regex but it only works with 2 floating point like 1.22, 300.33 but if its solid numbers like 1,2,3 or 1 floating point it doesnt work.

```
            "priceFormat":{
                "regex": /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$|[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}[^0-9]/,
                "alertText": "* Invalid Price Format"
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```